# JavaScript Validation error?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a JavaScript validator, but for some reason, evalid always returns as false even if it has passed validation... this is a bug as if evalid is false, the form doesn't submit.

```
function signup_validate()
    {
        document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("password_error").innerHTML = "";
        evalid = false;
        pvalid = false;
        email = null;
        pass = null;
        confpass = null;
        email=document.forms["signup_form"]["email"].value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        atpos=email.indexOf("@");
        dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
        pass=document.forms["signup_form"]["pass"].value;
        confpass=document.forms["signup_form"]["confpass"].value;
            if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length)
            {
                document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = "<span class='required'>Email must be valid.</span>";
            }
            else
            {
                $.post('/resources/forms/signup.php',{email: email}, function(data){
                    if(data.exists){
                        document.getElementById("email_error").innerHTML = "<span class='required'>This email is already in use.</span>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        evalid = true;
                    }
                }, 'JSON');
            }
            if (pass!=""&&pass!=null&&confpass!=""&&confpass!=null&&confpass==pass)
            {
                pvalid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("password_error").innerHTML = "<span class='required'>Both passwords must match and cannot be left blank.</span>";
            }
            alert(evalid);
            if (evalid == true && pvalid == true)
            {
                document.getElementById("signup_form").submit();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

What could I have missed?

Comment: Where are you returning evalid. What I see is your function gets to the end and returns nothing.

Comment: Why aren't you declaring any variables? hello `var`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only moment when you set "evalid" true is inside a function that runs asynchronously. In other words, by the time you set "evalid" true the main function has already reached the end.

You Could try to use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` and use the parameter `async:false`

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',       
    url: '/resources/forms/signup.php',
    data: {email: email},
    success: function(response){
        //your function here
    },
    dataType:'JSON',
    async:false
});
```

Comment: ok, then how would I rectify this? I see where you are going, as it makes sense now.

Comment: im a bit new to javascript so im not sure what the solution would be.

Comment: @fermionoid: You have two options. 1. Do a synchronous request. 2. Use a callback.

Comment: @elclanrs how would I make this synchronous? sorry, JS noob :)

Comment: I mean without using $.ajax as now i need to rewrite my script... i dont know how i would do that...

Comment: if I were to use $.ajax can you show me a demo with what I need to replace my submitted $.post with?

Comment: `$.post` is just a shortcut for [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with some defaults already set. Read the docs on it. There's an option as Josep said called `async`.

Comment: @elclanrs i get that but how will i make it work with my code, thats what's giving me a headache.

Comment: wait for the success part, how will i do the data.exists thing?

Comment: so umm for my validation function, what will represent `data` for `data.exists`?

Comment: oh, ok so response is what represents data. thanks, let me give it a shot then ill mark it as answer :)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I will use $.ajax from now on!